# Sum of two columns and merge them in a Json row

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table that have two json columns. The table is like below:

```
┌────────────────────────┐──────────────────────────┐
│       source           │         destination      │
├────────────────────────┤──────────────────────────┤
│ {"a": 5, "b": 6}       │    {"c": 9, "y":1}       │
│ {"b": 6, "c": 9}       │    {"x": 25,"y":5}       │
└────────────────────────┘──────────────────────────┘
```

Is there any way to write a **SELECT** that 1) extracts each key/value from each row and 2) sums their value like below?

```
┌────────────────────────┐──────────────────────────┐
│       source           │         destination      │
├────────────────────────┤──────────────────────────┤
│ {"a": 5}               │         {"c": 9}         │
│ {"b": 12}              │         {"x": 25}        │
| {"c": 9}               |         {"y":6}          |
└────────────────────────┘──────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Which version of PG are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shaky undertaking at the best of times. Breaking up the json, summing values by keys and then building a simple json is easy enough, but doing it over two columns is a bit odd and most certainly ignoring everything that is good about relational entity modeling (but then again, you are already using json so halfway down a very slippery path...) but here goes:

**PG9.4+**

Using `jsonb`.

```
SELECT json_build_object(srckey, srcsum) AS source,
       json_build_object(destkey, destsum) AS destination
FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn, srckey, srcsum
  FROM (
    SELECT srckey, sum(srcval::int) AS srcsum
    FROM my_table
    JOIN jsonb_each_text(my_table.source) kv(srckey, srcval) ON true
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1) sub
  ) subsrc
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn, destkey, destsum
  FROM (
    SELECT destkey, sum(destval::int) AS destsum
    FROM my_table
    JOIN jsonb_each_text(my_table.destination) kv(destkey, destval) ON true
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1) sub2
  ) subdest USING (rn);
```